# How to silence Terracotta logging to console on client

Tags: logging, terracotta

Using the Terracotta client, the following is **always** logged to the console at application startup.  I am looking to silence this output.

Changes to my own log4j.xml have no effect on this output.  Please advise how I can silence this output.  Changing the console output to WARN is acceptable.

Logged output:

```
2014-08-08 11:34:41,017 INFO - Terracotta 3.7.7, as of 20140117-102107 (Revision 24373 by jenkins-slave@sfo-c64-jenkins-slave-007.eur.ad.sag from 3.7.7)
2014-08-08 11:34:41,361 INFO - Successfully loaded base configuration from file at '/var/folders/lj/_ny27bys3gl_y6d73tm940l00000gn/T/tc-config8417820335658989224.xml'.
2014-08-08 11:34:41,374 INFO - Log file: '/tmp/terracotta/logs/terracotta-client.log'.
2014-08-08 11:34:42,249 INFO - Connection successfully established to server at 127.0.0.1:9510
objc[43446]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```